# If $I\pi ^{-k}\subseteq D$ for all $k\leq m$ but $I\pi ^{-m-1}\nsubseteq D$, then $I\pi ^{-m}\nsubseteq (\pi )$

Tags: commutative-algebra

I'm working through a proof and I've got stuck on one detail, it seems like it is supposed to be totally obvious, but need help to figure out why.

> Let $D$ be a Noetherian integrally closed domain with unique prime ideal $(\pi)$. For an ideal $I$ of $D$ we have that $I\pi ^{-k} \subseteq D$ for all $k\leq m$ but $I\pi ^{-m-1}\nsubseteq D$. I wonder how to make the conclusion that $I\pi ^{-m}\nsubseteq (\pi )$.

This is used in proving that every ideal in the ring $D$ above is a power of $(\pi )$. I hope I didn't leave out any crucial information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $I\pi^{-m}\subseteq(\pi)$. Then every element of $I\pi^{-m}$ is of the form $\pi a$ for some $a\in D$. Thus, every element of $I\pi^{-m-1}$ is an element of $D$, i.e. $I\pi^{-m-1}\subseteq D$; but we chose $m$ so that this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Since $D$ is a domain, one should say that $(\pi)$ is the unique *non-zero* prime ideal. If so, $D$ has dimension $1$ and thus is a Dedekind domain (by definition).

One knows that in a Dedekind domain an ideal is always a product of prime ideals. Thus, a fortiori, the products $(\pi)^n=(\pi^n)$ are all the non-zero ideals that there might be.

This is the approach taken, for instance, by P. Samuel in his classic *Théorie Algébrique des Nombres*